# Listview Firebase Flutter The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show data from firebase in a listView

I just want to show the id of my collection

but I have problem with  **title: doc.data()["id"],**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemandeList extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demandes listes"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection('demande').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                     title: doc.data()["id"],
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Feel free to accept or upvote if my answer is satisfied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
doc.id;
// Or doc.Id;
```

Instead of

```
doc.data()['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to a Flutter update.

In the newest Flutter update, there is no need of adding '.data()'.

Removing the '.data()' from the code should solve the issue.